# How can I typeset this mathematical expression?

Tags: math-mode

How can I typeset this mathematical expression?

[image]

Comment: `\langle w, \tilde{w} \rangle`? `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda Does the `:)` go inside or outside the dollar delimiters? 8^b

Comment: @Steven: ooh I think we might end up with some incorret kerning. `:)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it's a “one shot”, then

```
$\langle w,\tilde{w}\rangle$
```

will be sufficient. If you have several inner products to typeset it is surely better to define a personal command for them; there are several possibilities. The simplest one is

```
\newcommand{\innp}[1]{\langle #1\rangle}
```

to be called as

```
$\innp{w,\tilde{w}}$
$\innp{x,y}$
```

Defining a command is really recommended. If you change your mind and decide that inner products should be typeset like

> ```
> (x | y)
> ```

you'd have to hunt through your document in order to find out the instances of `\langle` and retype the correct code: the chances of errors are very high. Even if you're really convinced about the notation, using a new command is better, because, for instance, you can search for all inner products very easily.

Now let's try our hand at a more complicated definition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

% first version
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\innp}[1]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1}

\begin{document}

$\innp{w,\tilde{w}}$
\[
\innp[\Big]{w,\frac{w}{\norm{w}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now, suppose you change your mind and want the alternative notation. Here's how you can do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

% second version
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\innp}[1]{(}{)}{\innpargs{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\innpargs}{ >{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m }
 {\innpargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\innpargsaux}{ m m }
 {#1\;\delimsize\vert\;#2}

\begin{document}

$\innp{w,\tilde{w}}$
\[
\innp[\Big]{w,\frac{w}{\norm{w}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just a modified definition of `\innp` allows you to completely change the appearance of the inner products.

#### Some note on the second version

We want to keep the very convenient input form

```
\innp{x,y}
```

but still exploit the features in `mathtools`. With

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\innp}[2]{(}{)}{#1\;\delimsize\vert\;#2}
```

we would be forced to change syntax into `\innp{x}{y}`. But we can use `xparse`: with

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\innp}[1]{(}{)}{\innpargs{#1}}
```

we set up the delimiter interface of `mathtools`; now with

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\innpargs}{ >{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m }
 {\innpargsaux#1}
```

we tell `xparse` to take the argument to `\innpargs` and split into two pieces at the comma; these will become the two arguments for `\innpargsaux`, which finally does what we'd like to, like in the two argument form discussed before.

Comment: Please explain the second macro in more details. This looks very elegant and I would like to understand what's going on.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I added some explanations.

Comment: @egreg: beautiful! I'll adapt at once my macros using `DeclarePairedDelimitersX`. I really learnt something important!

Answer (score 5):

To have a correct horizontal spacing and delimiters that adapt to the size of what's inside, you can use the `mathtools` package (it loads and extends `amsmath`). You have commands to define "paired delimiters" such as a scalar (inner) product:

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\innerp[2]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1\,,\,#2}
```

Then you'll have two versions for inner products: `\innerp*` will internally add a  `\left` and a `\right` before \langle and \rangle respectively. For fine-tuning of the size of delimiters, `\innerp` (without a star) accepts an optional argument `\big`, `\Big`, &c.

In your case it should be used as `\innerp{w}{\tilde w}`. Of course you can define a shortcut command:

```
\newcommand\foo[1]{\innerp{#1}{\widetilde{#1}}
```

and simply write `\foo{w}`.

Comment: I thought that this was just a simple command!

Comment: It can be, if you're not very fastidious.;)

Comment: @Bernard, does `innerp` have 1 or 2 arguments? See your `foo` definition.

Comment: @Sigur: Thanks for pointing me the error. Iw as so much of thinking mathematically that it took me a couple of minutes  to understand what the problem was.

Comment: @Adam I love LaTeX—I really, really do—but it's times like these that teach me you can make *anything* complicated if you try hard enough. `:)`

Comment: @SeanAllred good point.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [physics](http://ctan.org/pkg/physics) package. It provides quite a lot of macros that are useful. The following code does what you want and in my opinion, it is quite simple :-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}
  \[ \ev{w,\tilde{w}}. \]
\end{document}
```

Here \ev stands for expectation value.